# When switching from html to visual editor the <p> tag gets erased

Tags: tags

I'm facing a problem, basically if I use the

tags into the html and then change to visual editor, the tags disappear, and it stays in plain text.

Scenario:

- In HTML mode, I add some p tags to a post I'm editing.
- I switch to Visual, then back to HTML, and the tag and all of its content are gone.

I'm not using any extended tinymce plugin.

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't save `<p>` tags.  Paragraphs are displayed automatically in the TinyMCE visual editor and then the output gets `<p>` tags automatically (for better or for worse) from the `wpautop` function.

I avoid using `<p>` tags.  A double line break will automatically be converted to a paragraph at output.

Comment: so basically, there is not any change to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as far as I know.  Sorry that the answer is "there is no answer".  You could disable the visual editor, but then you will always be obliged to work in HTML-mode.  Why do you need a special `<p>`?  Maybe there is another approach we could find.

Comment: I just didn't want to give a general line height to the body, and keep it only for paragraphs, however there is not other way. Thanks a ton for you answer.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. `wpautop` adds `<br />` when it finds a line break; it doesn't strip out `<p>` tags (according to the docs, anyway). Disabling `wpautop` doesn't fix this issue.